# Select Features grayed out in PythonAddins toolbar

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.4, select, python-addin

I've created a custom toolbar using the `pythonaddins` module. For ease of use I'd like to add the `Select Features` tool to the toolbar.

[image]

The tool becomes grayed out as soon as I close the `Customize` window however.

[image]

Note that the `Select Features` tool on the `Tools` toolbar works fine.

[image]

Comment: Are no layers set to selectable? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12927/setting-which-layers-are-selectable-in-arcmap are you sure your active active data frame has selectable layers? Is the spatial reference set? In previous versions the selection was disabled if the spatial reference of the dataframe was set to unknown.

Comment: @MichaelStimson That's not it. The Select Features tool on the Tools toolbar works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are adding an item that is not the same as the `Select Features` on the `Tools` toolbar. The `Select Features` from the `Data View Context Menu` is the tool that one can start once right-clicking in the data view.

What you are looking for is tools under `Selection` category:

[image]

Unfortunately, you won't be able to have the same drop-down menu of the tools to pick from (by lasso, polygon, line etc) because this is done by some custom ArcMap UI code that is not exposed through `Customize` menu.

The closest you can get is either to have just `Select By Rectangle` (which is the default for built-in `Select Features` group tool) or to add multiple selection types to the toolbar:

[image]